# Tensorflow > 2GB array as an input for tf.slice_input_producer

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, numpy, tensorflow

Using python3 and tensorflow, I've tried to put my data as training data into `tf.train.slice_input_producer` and `tf.train.shuffle_batch`

```
def batch_data():
    ...
    # trX as training_data and trY as training_labels.
    # Both are numpy array
    data_queues = tf.train.slice_input_producer([trX, trY])
    X, Y = tf.train.shuffle_batch(data_queues, num_threads=num_threads,
                                  batch_size=batch_size,
                                  capacity=batch_size * 64,
                                  min_after_dequeue=batch_size * 32,
                                  allow_smaller_final_batch=False)
    return X, Y
```

But I got error Tensor > 2GB:

```
data_queues = tf.train.slice_input_producer([trX, trY])
  File "C:\Users\ellamunde\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda2\envs\python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\input.py", line 302, in slice_input_producer
    tensor_list = ops.convert_n_to_tensor_or_indexed_slices(tensor_list)
  File "C:\Users\ellamunde\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda2\envs\python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 1153, in convert_n_to_tensor_or_indexed_slices
    values=values, dtype=dtype, name=name, as_ref=False)
  File "C:\Users\ellamunde\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda2\envs\python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 1124, in internal_convert_n_to_tensor_or_indexed_slices
    value, dtype=dtype, name=n, as_ref=as_ref))
  File "C:\Users\ellamunde\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda2\envs\python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 1083, in internal_convert_to_tensor_or_indexed_slices
    value, dtype=dtype, name=name, as_ref=as_ref)
  File "C:\Users\ellamunde\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda2\envs\python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 926, in internal_convert_to_tensor
    ret = conversion_func(value, dtype=dtype, name=name, as_ref=as_ref)
  File "C:\Users\ellamunde\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda2\envs\python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\constant_op.py", line 229, in _constant_tensor_conversion_function
    return constant(v, dtype=dtype, name=name)
  File "C:\Users\ellamunde\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda2\envs\python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\constant_op.py", line 208, in constant
    value, dtype=dtype, shape=shape, verify_shape=verify_shape))
  File "C:\Users\ellamunde\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda2\envs\python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\tensor_util.py", line 447, in make_tensor_proto
    "Cannot create a tensor proto whose content is larger than 2GB.")
ValueError: Cannot create a tensor proto whose content is larger than 2GB.
```

I tried to handle it with variable

```
def batch_data():
...
    Xplaceholder = tf.placeholder(trX.dtype, shape=trX.shape, name='Xplaceholder')
    Xvar = tf.get_variable('XVariable', shape=trX.shape, dtype=trX.dtype, initializer=tf.zeros_initializer())
    Yplaceholder = tf.placeholder(trY.dtype, shape=trY.shape, name='Yplaceholder')
    Yvar = tf.get_variable('YVariable', shape=trY.shape, dtype=trY.dtype, initializer=tf.zeros_initializer())
    Xassign = Xvar.assign(Xplaceholder)
    Yassign = Yvar.assign(Yplaceholder)

    with tf.Session() as session:
        session.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
        session.run(Xassign, feed_dict={Xplaceholder: trX})
        session.run(Yassign, feed_dict={Yplaceholder: trY})
        session.close()

    data_queues = tf.train.slice_input_producer([Xvar, Yvar])
    X, Y = tf.train.shuffle_batch(data_queues, num_threads=num_threads,
                                  batch_size=batch_size,
                                  capacity=batch_size * 64,
                                  min_after_dequeue=batch_size * 32,
                                  allow_smaller_final_batch=False)
```

Actually, it works. But when I monitored the loss value for each training was different and the loss value always increase each training and never decrease.

Does anybody can give me insight why does it happen?
Thanks