# Tensorflow tf.train.shuffle_batch() Cannot create a tensor proto whose content is larger than 2GB

Tags: python, python-2.7, tensorflow, machine-learning, gpu

I have some trouble using tf.train.shuffle_batch() on a large dataset.
I'm using it like that :

```
x_train, y_train = tf.train.shuffle_batch(
    [images["train"], labels["train"]],
    batch_size=self.batch_size,            #I reduced it to 8
    capacity=50000,
    enqueue_many=True,
    min_after_dequeue=0,
    num_threads=16,
    seed=self.seed,
    allow_smaller_final_batch=True,
  )
```

Where :

```
images["train"].shape = (88179,64,64,3) #Training set of tiny-Imagenet
labels["train"].shape = (88179,)        #Related labels
```

and it output me this error :

```
ValueError: Cannot create a tensor proto whose content is larger than 2GB.
```

Indeed I tried on a smaller dataset (CIFAR-10) where shapes are smaller (and 160 of batch_size) :

```
images["train"].shape = (45000,32,32,3) #Training set of CIFAR-10
labels["train"].shape = (45000,)        #Related labels
```

and tf.train.shuffle_batch() work perfectly.

I saw a lot of Questions on this issue but none where people use tf.train.shuffle_batch() (I saw one but without answer in fact : [Tensorflow > 2GB array as an input for tf.slice_input_producer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48404534/tensorflow-2gb-array-as-an-input-for-tf-slice-input-producer))

Does someone has an idea ?

[CONFIG : TITAN X 12Go, 32Go RAM, tensorflow 1.4.1, python 2.7.15, CUDA 8.0]

Comment: Any answer on this ? I am facing the same issue